Emit TrackFinished event when playback of current track get finished
PlaybackActiveTrackChanged event is emitted multiple times no matter what made current track to change. So, a more accurate TrackPlaybackFinshed event should be emitted.
I get PlaybackActiveTrackChanged event even when I skip to next or previous track on clicking skip buttons from notification or calling TrackPlayer.skip and it makes the react native app to render multiple times.
